# Updating State Value Across File Functions in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx, react-props

I'd like my code to update the variable "currentPage" across file functions (App.js and startMenu.js). Currently I can do so with states using only App.js, but would like to simplify my code such that I can use other *.js files in the directory. Right now startMenu.js is calling from App.js in the form of App.toMainMenu and App.toLevelBuilder, but it is not updating the state variable, "currentPage" onClick like I'd like it to.

**App.js:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import startMenu from "./startMenu";
import levelBuilder from "./levelBuilder";

function App(){
  
  const[currentPage, setPage] = useState("start")

  function toMainMenu(){
    setPage(prevPage => "main")
  }

  function toLevelBuilder(){
    setPage(prevPage => "levels")
  }

  function renderSwitch(param) {
    switch(param) {
      case 'levels':
        return levelBuilder();
      default:
        return startMenu();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div >            
          <span>{currentPage}</span>
          {renderSwitch(currentPage)}            
    </div>
  )
  
}
export default App;
```

**startMenu.js**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import levelBuilder from "./levelBuilder";
import App from "./App";

function startMenu() {
    return(
        <div className="container">      
            {/* start menu */}
            <img id = "scan_logo"src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/scanlogo.png'} /> 
            <button id="menuStart" onClick={App.toMainMenu}> START </button>
            <button id="menuLevel" onClick={App.toLevelBuilder}> LEVEL BUILDER </button>        
        </div>
    )
}
export default startMenu;
```

I was thinking I need to use props but as a React.js beginner, this confuses me slightly. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using functional components over class components?

Comment: You could put your code on a codesandbox to facilitate

Comment: Functional components and hooks is the way to go.

Comment: I'm using functional components as I was under the impression one can't use states with class components

Comment: If you want your state to be managed across your components you will need to either use the [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) library or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have two pages, the Main Menu, and the Level Builder, and you want to switch which one is beeing rendered, right? The best way to do this is by using the library react-router-dom, to create routes in your app, you can find more about it [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

But, if you really want to use the plain react state to do this, you can pass the function `setPage()` as props to the other two components, and call it from them. This should work too.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I'm not mistaken, react router modifies the url and I am trying to have the code run under the same domain name. As for passing setPage as a prop, could you provide an example by chance?

Comment: You gotta pass `setPage` as an argument to the functional components, like this `levelBuilder(setPage)` and `mainMenu(setPage)`. Then, inside the components you have to call it inside the `onClick`. In this case, you'd have to put the `toMainMenu()` and `toLevelBuilder()` inside each respective component, or just call `setPage("levels")` directly from `onClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using functional components. I wrote this at home on a text file so it might not compile however if you are looking to call your parent functions from your child functional components this is one way of doing it.

## app.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import StartMenu from "./StartMenu";
import LevelBuilder from "./LevelBuilder";

function App(){
    const [currentPage, setPage] = useState("start")

    function toMainMenu(){
        setPage(prevPage => "main")
    }

    function toLevelBuilder(){
        setPage(prevPage => "levels")
    }

    
    let jsx_element = null;

    switch(currentPage){
        case 'levels':
            jsx_element = <LevelBuilder/>;
            break;
        default:
            jsx_element = <StartMenu toMainMenu={toMainMenu} toLevelBuilder={toLevelBuilder}/>; 
    }

    return (
        <div>            
            <span>{currentPage}</span>
            {jsx_element}            
        </div>
    )

    }
export default App;
```

## StartMenu.js

```
import React from "react";

function StartMenu(props) {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <img id = "scan_logo"src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/scanlogo.png'} /> 
            <button id="menuStart" onClick={props.toMainMenu}> START </button>
            <button id="menuLevel" onClick={props.toLevelBuilder}> LEVEL BUILDER </button>        
        </div>
    )
}
export default StartMenu;
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it seems that startMenu still doesn't have access to App.js. With your changes, I am currently getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toMainMenu' of undefined" which I presume is because startMenu.js doesn't know where to find toMainMenu()

Comment: There are a couple small things wrong with Null's code, but would not cause the error you are having.  Your error is saying that `props` is undefined in StartMenu.js, which it is not. Here is a codesandbox of it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lehmann-8lgoc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

First a few small pointers:

- your component names (`startMenu`, `levelBuilder`) should use Pascal Case
- it is common practice for the state variable and the "set" function names to match, i.e. `currentPage` and `setCurrentPage`

The best way for you would probably be to pass `setCurrentPage` into `<StartMenu />` from `<App />`. Then in `<StartMenu />` when the user clicks on a button you can call `setCurrentPage('...')`.

Another thing you could do (but is overkill for you) is to look into `useContext`.